# Usage of '${spring.version}'

Tags: java, spring, maven

When I use:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

on the console I get the following error message:

> 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework:spring-context:jar must be a valid version but is '${spring.version}'. @ line 40, column 19

Do I have to do a manually configuration of Maven? I've seen this kind of dependency but there is no explanation how to do it properly.

Comment: What does the rest of your pom.xml look like? Is spring.version defined as a property?

Comment: use axtavts solution or hardcode the spring version it makes no difference

Answer (score 50):

`${spring.version}` is a placeholder, you need to configure its actual value in `<properties>` block:

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't really agree with the first answer.

Using `${spring.version}` is a convenient way to config version.

In xml file, you need to set property like follow:

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>4.3.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>
```

Then it will work.

Answer (score 2):

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>4.3.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
</properties>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

if you want to use **${spring.version}** then first define its version in **properties** tag and it is good practice to use to define the version in properties tag because if we change the version then we don't need to do changes in the entire file just do change in properties tag.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple answer for that. 

Add **spring.version** to properties section in `pom.xml`.

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>4.0.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>
```