# How to add Spring libs using Maven

Tags: java, spring, maven

I learned Spring via Spring In Action 3 few month ago. I downloaded Spring libraries from official site (list was like in SIA3(aop, asm, aspects, beans ...)), added them to my project and everything worked fine. Now I want to use Maven, but I am getting a lot of errors and sinking in searching what library to add.

I am newby, dont know all Spring dependencies(within it libs) and the question is not about my errors, but about the way to add all Spring libraries to my project via Maven. How do you usually add Spring libs using Maven?

Comment: It's there on the Spring homepage.

Comment: @Raedwald But it's quite hard to find this answer on official site.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't have to download the libraries themselves anymore. That is what [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) is for. (and quite some more, of course)

- set up Maven properly
- set up Maven in the IDE tool you have (like [this](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-ide-eclipse.html))
- edit the [`pom.xml`](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html) to include what you need, adding the dependencies in the in the `dependencies` tag.
- Maven takes care of resolving the dependencies of the specified packages. If a package depends on other packages, it will do it for you. **You only have to specify the packages you directly need**

For example

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring</artifactId>
<version>2.5.6</version>
</dependency>
```

You can easily find the packages using Google, and searching for "maven repository "

#### Avoiding version clashes

Also, as **Bart** mentioned, the common way of having Spring in the pom.xml - as it has way too many versions, and clashes can occur - is through a common property specifying the version for all Spring components. ([Based on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197311/usage-of-spring-version))

Specify the property in the `properties` tag:

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>
```

Then use it in the dependencies like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

**Be careful** to use it for **ALL** components to avoid version clashes. (of course, issues mught still occur, bz having different libraries reference spring too, but that is another story in its own.)

#### Side note

Keep in mind note that Maven projects use specific [**directory layout**](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html). When I first started using maven for my own projects, first I created a new blank one, and played around with it, before I began migrating my older projects to use maven. Believe me, it pays off.

Comment: Since the spring framework has many modules available and you don't want to get into a version clash between classes it's very common to use a property to denote the version.

Comment: @Bart that is true, I was hesitant to add it in the first place, as OP is still in the beginning, but as the aswer is more complete, I edited it to have this too... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add spring artifacts to your pom.xml file. For example

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
<version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
```

You can find more artifact info here
http://mvnrepository.com/

Answer (score 0):

[HERE](https://mvnrepository.com/search?q=spring) you can find the dependencies as per your requirement. Just click on the dependency and inside click on the latest release, scroll down there is your code inside the `<dependencies> Your required dependency and version</dependencies>`.

Just copy the `XML` code and paste it in your `pom.xml` file.